# Facebook like button on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

I added a like button to my index.php and single.php on yssencial.com (using wordpress)

but on the main page (index.php) it is not sharing the article but the site url (www.yssencial.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the data-href property of the individual posts to your posts url.  Otherwise it will use the page that it is actually on, eg your home page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.yssencial.com/2011/09/20/terra-nova-quando-o-parque-jurassico-encontra-a-maquina-do-tempo/" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="140" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: i'm sorry, can you explain that in other words.

again, what i'm saying is that when i'm on the main page, the like button on each article points to www.yssencial.com and not the article url.

when i'm on the article url it works OK.

if i install one of those wordpress plugins that put the facebook like button on top of the articles, it works ok, the problem is it is not positioned where i want it to be